# hystrix circuit short-circuited and is open android

Tags: android, navigation

I put the following code in activity extends **Fragment** implement **NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener**

When I click on the button and the button must request an ad
I get this error that is shown as toast.
And I did not get error before I put this code in

```js
@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
  int id = item.getItemId();
  if (id == R.id.navigation_gift) {
    TextView txtEmtiaz = (TextView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.txtEmtiaz);
    SharedPreferences sp1 = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("entire", 0);
    String oop = sp1.getString("emtiaz", "");
    txtEmtiaz.setText(oop);
    Log.e("POPI", "txt in Ads fragment Saved :" + txtEmtiaz.getText());
  } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
  } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {
  } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {
  } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {
  } else if (id == R.id.nav_help_WITHUS) {
  }
  return true;
}
```

Error Toast : hystrix circuit short-circuited and is open android